# Is this a Php timeout or MySQL timeout for the session? How to resolve?

Tags: php, mysql, session, timeout

This is a new Linux server running Apache 2, Php 7.1.29, MySQL 5.x.

Users open a .php page and must log in. Their accounts are in a MySQL database. A user's session to the web server application (Php and MySQL) appears to timeout frequently after a certain amount of idle time. Not sure if it's Php or MySQL related and where to increase a timeout setting.

So far, I have increased session.gc_maxlifetime from default 14400 to 86400 which has not resolved the issue. I've also increased the Session Idle Time at the server to 600 min via Plesk panel.

Comment: We need to see PHP code and MySQL tables and same data in it.. Mine best geuss with this limited information is that the PHP session cookie expires or the cookie is not correctly set.. There you simply to much things that could be wrong..

Comment: [This link](https://solutionfactor.net/blog/2014/02/08/implementing-session-timeout-with-php/) is a good reference for implementing session timeout in PHP. As indicated above, your cookie might be expiring or not set. The parameter you're looking for is `session.cookie_lifetime`.

Comment: My apologies. I failed to mention that session.cookie_lifetime is set to 0 which means "until the browser is closed". I'm not sure what code to include that will be helpful, Raymond.  Thank you.

Comment: I took a look at the cookie and see Expires set to N/A (PHPSESSID).